# Does c++14 literal operator only support long double and unsigned long long type?

Tags: c++, c++14, user-defined-literals

I've tried this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
constexpr int operator"" _w(int d) { return d; }
struct Watt {
    int d;
    Watt(int _d) : d(_d) {}
};
Watt operator "" _watt(int d) { return Watt(d); }

int main() {
    Watt w1 = 17_w;
    cout << w1.d << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with clang++ 14, it gives:

```
<source>:3:29: error: invalid literal operator parameter type 'int', did you mean 'unsigned long long'?
constexpr int operator"" _w(int d) { return d; }
                            ^~~~~
<source>:8:24: error: invalid literal operator parameter type 'int', did you mean 'unsigned long long'?
Watt operator "" _watt(int d) { return Watt(d); }
                       ^~~~~
<source>:11:17: error: no matching literal operator for call to 'operator""_w' with argument of type 'unsigned long long' or 'const char *', and no matching literal operator template
    Watt w1 = 17_w;
```

Just wish to know, whether c++14's literal operator limits to support certain restricted data types? Is `int` type feasible here in my code? If yes, how to fix it?

Comment: It only sports the widest type for each kind.

Comment: Even if the operator uses an `unsigned long long` parameter, it can still return an int (or whatever you like). Just like [chrono::""min](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22min) returns minutes.

Answer (score 1):

From [Literal_operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal#Literal_operators)

`int` is not part of allowed parameters lists:

> - `( const char * )`  (1)
> - `( unsigned long long int )`    (2)
> - `( long double )`   (3)
> - `( char )`  (4)
> - `( wchar_t )`   (5)
> - `( char8_t )`   (6)     (since C++20)
> - `( char16_t )`  (7)
> - `( char32_t )`  (8)
> - `( const char * , std::size_t )`    (9)
> - `( const wchar_t * , std::size_t )`     (10)
> - `( const char8_t * , std::size_t )`     (11)    (since C++20)
> - `( const char16_t * , std::size_t )`    (12)
> - `( const char32_t * , std::size_t )`    (13)

You have to use `unsigned long long int` instead (as suggested by your compiler).